# Generalizing road polylines?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.3, road, generalization

I have a dataset of road lines obtained from digitized aerial imagery and I want to automate the generalization procedures using arcGIS model builder. I am using the ArcGIS 10.3 desktop suite. I have come across the generalization toolset in ArcGIS. But I'm not sure as I may not have understood the theory in generalizing roads.

What procedures can I use in a workflow?

And especially, since I'm generalizing from my source data at 1 in 2500, to an output of 1 in 20k how can i calculate the parameters to use for a 20k map generalization module?

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google search for "techniques for generalizing roads" threw up this

- [Continuous_Road_Network_Generalisation.pdf](http://www.gdmc.nl/publications/2014/Continuous_Road_Network_Generalisation.pdf)
- [Selection of roads](http://www.isprs.org/proceedings/XXXVII/congress/4_pdf/109.pdf)
- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartographic_generalization)

Comment: This is brilliant. But more specifically, I'm looking to find parameters to suit a scale of 1 in 20000 and another for 1 in 50000.
Any ideas  on this too?